# Process filenames with spaces listed in text file

Tags: bash

I have a list of files listed in a text file named "list.txt", like this:

```
one file.jpg 
two file.jpg 
three file.jpg
```

Now I want to copy all this files to another directory, and I try this:

> cp $( cat list.txt ) other_directory

but, as you can see, there are space in the files, and then bash breaks the names in two, and no file is copied.

I've tried surrounding the names with quote and double quote, and I tried escape with backslash and
space(\ ), and also combinations of it, to no avail.

```
"one file.jpg"
'one file.jpg'
one\ file.jpg
```

So, what do I do?

Comment: Serverfault is for questions about server management, not general shell scripting. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) would be a better place to ask about this, but look for similar questions first and also check out [BashFAQ #1 (reading a file line-by-line)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [#20 (handling filenames with spaces)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020). [Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is also handy to sanity-check your scripts for common mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This copies the files one by one (ie. one file per `cp` command), enclosing each source filename in double quotes:

```
awk '{ print "cp \"" $0 "\" other_directory }' list.txt | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

for the specific case of `cp` (and `mv`, `ln` etc), this should work:

```
cat list.txt | xargs -d $'\n' cp -t b
```

That's because the `-t` allows you to run `cp` in a way that the arguments come at the end.